# Issues with C linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a function to insert a struct into a queue implemented as a linked list.
I am passing an array element as the process.

```
void q_insert (queue *q, process p) {
  printf("before insert attemp\n");
  if (q->head == NULL) {
    q->head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    q->head->process = &p;
    q->head->next = NULL;
    q->tail = q->head;
    printf("After insertion into empty\n");
  }
  else {
    struct Node* temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->process = &p;
    temp->next = NULL;
    q->tail->next = temp;
    q->tail = temp;
    printf("after insertion into non empty\n");
  }
}
```

When I call this function the first time on an empty list, it seems to work fine. When I try to insert a second item it adds the second entry, but it also replaces the first entry with a copy of the second. These are the structs used:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[80];
  int arrival_time;
  int execution_time;
  int priority;     // high number is high priority
} process;

struct Node{
  process* process;
  struct Node* next;
} q_node;

typedef struct {
  struct Node* head;
  struct Node* tail;
} queue;
```

Comment: `q->head->process = &p;` : `p` is local value in `q_insert ` function. example of fix E.g `process* process;` --> `process process;`.. `q->head->process = p;`

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY Awesome. Thanks. Haven't used C pointers in about a year. Forgot more than i thought. Youre saving me right now.

Answer (score 0):

C only supports `pass by value` and when you pass the `address` of variable through pointer, the copy of the address that variable passes,and in your `insert` function When `q == NULL`, you're allocating memory and assigning that memory to `q`, but this won't change `q` outside your function: only the copy of `q` *inside* your function will be changed.

In order to change what the argument `q` *points to*, and have those changes reflected outside your function, you'll need to pass a pointer to a pointer like this:

```
void q_insert (struct node **q, process p) {
  if (q->head == NULL) {
  struct node* new_head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new_head->head->next = NULL; 
  .
  .
  *q=new_head;
  .
  .
 }
```

Comment: Im calling the function like this:    q_insert(&wait_queue, list[next]);   and it seems to work fine. I print from wait_queue and the information is correct.

Comment: yeah that's correct because `&wait_queue` is pointer to pointer `queue` or `struct node`

Comment: @krpra how is `&wait_queue` a pointer to pointer of `queue` and why do you say "or `struct node`". `struct Node` and `queue` are two different `struct` types.

Comment: How is `wait_queue` declared here ? If it is `queue *wait_queue`, I guess it is fine then